# Stop Vertical Scrolling on right click using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, vertical-scrolling

In my application when user presses right click I display some options to user and when user clicks on any option like copy page is scroll to top always.

I just need to stop the page scrolling.

I have tried to use animate method of jQuery, but this is not working.

```
$('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#CopyImage').offset().top
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you `copy` option is a element like that:

```
<a href='#' >copy</a>
```

just replace `#` with `javascript: void 0;`

Answer (score 0):

replace # in href with `javascript: void (0);`